# How can restrict active directory permissions in Azure?

Tags: azure, active-directory, terraform, rbac

I'm looking to implement RBAC for our Azure users. I've created various Active Directory groups (super user, admin, member) and locking down permissions.

One permission I'm looking for is to restrict the AD group membership to only be changed by the super user group members.

Can anyone point me as to which `actions` and/or `data_actions` I need to grant/restrict?

If it's relevant, I'm doing it in Terraform.

```
resource "azuread_group" "superuser" {
  name = "Super User"
}

resource "azuerad_group" "team" {
  name = "Team"
}

resource "azurerm_role_definition" "superuser-add-user-to-team-group" {
  name = "Super User: add to team"
  scope = "${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}"

  // It's this block I need the permissions for
  permissions {
    actions = ["*"]
    data_actions = ["*"]
  }

  assignable_scopes = [
    "${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}" // @todo put in the scope for the Team AD Group
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "assign-add-user-to-team-group-to-superuser-group" {
  scope = "${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}"
  role_definition_id = "${azurerm_role_definition."superuser-add-user-to-team-group".id}"
  principal_id = "${azuread_group.superuser.id}"
}
```

Comment: AD group membership controlling permissions are Azure AD level permissions, not Azure RBAC. They are controlled with directory roles. Usually a regular user does have to be assigned as one of the owners of a group to be able to modify members.

Comment: Can I know what you want to do to restrict the AD group members? Control the resources in the subscription or just control the  Azure users?